# Blackberry VOIP client

Tags: blackberry, voip

I want to start to implement the VOIP client for blackberry, but seeing the Blackberry api I feel that its not possible to build the VOIP client for Blackberyy. So I think there must be a different approach in implementing the client......

So any one have idea about it.... thanks in advance....

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible? There's already Skype and Google Voice for BB, so I don't see a reason why a VoIP client shouldn't be possible too.

Comment: Ya I know that but I am sure that they might have chosen some different approach to implement. Using only Blackberry SDK its not possible. If you know something about that then tell me....

Comment: What APIs are you missing in Blackberry SDK? BTW, Google Voice is not VoIP

Comment: I am missing the API regarding the control of player and recorder. I want to tell the recorder that when you record the 160 bytes gibe me call back. So can I do that? There is no api to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fgmicrotec offers an SDK for BlackBerry VoIP development that offers exactly what you are looking for. Have a lokk at their website:

http://www.fgmicrotec.com/BlackBerry-VoIP.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are doing well. while I was making `R&D` for VoIP client for android then I was wonder after find that lib which is available for many platforms like Android,IOS,C++,C and BlackBerry too. then I found this is the best way to implement Voip. for blackberry see [here](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/BB10). hopefully, this link will help you. and most important thing is this lib is free and have good documentation and architecture [see.](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/pjsip-arch.jpg)

enjoy your code time:)